# Method working with days in a month not behaving

Tags: java, methods

So basically we have this question to do : Write a method dayNumber that determines the number of days in a year up to and including the current day. The method should have three int parameters: year, month, and day. If the value of any parameter is invalid, the method should print a warning message and return the value zero. The table gives some examples of the action of the method. Accept any non-negative year as being valid. You may want to assume the existence of a method numberOfDays that returns the number of days in a given month of a given year. And you should have a method call isLeapYear, if the user enter a year that is a leap year.

This is what I did so far....

```
class dayMonthYear {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Enter a year");
      int year = In.getInt();
      System.out.println("Enter the month for '1' to be January - '12' to be december");
      int month = In.getInt();
      System.out.println("Enter the day");
      int day = In.getInt();
      dayNumber(year, month, day);
      System.out.println(dayNumber(year, month, day));
   }

   public static int dayNumber(int year, int month, int day) {
      int total = 0;
      for (int m = 1; m < month; m++)
         total += (numberOfDays(month, year));
      return total + day;
   }

   public static boolean isLeapYear(int yearB) {
      return (yearB % 4 == 0 && yearB % 100 != 0) || yearB % 400 == 0;
   }

   public static int numberOfDays(int monthA, int yearA) {
      int days = 0;
      if (monthA == 4 || monthA == 6 || monthA == 9 || monthA == 11)
         days = 30;
      if (monthA == 1 || monthA == 3 || monthA == 5 || monthA == 7
            || monthA == 8 || monthA == 10 || monthA == 12)
         days = 31;
      else if (monthA == 2 && isLeapYear(yearA))
         days = 29;
      else if (monthA == 2)
         days = 28;
      return days;
   }
}
```

It works and compiles but my problem is that: let say I enter "12" for December and December has 31 days, so what my program will do since December has 31 days, it thinks each month has 31 days and add them up which will give me 372 when it's suppose to give me 365. How do I make it that it won't do that and that it will work if the year is a leap year too.

Comment: I see a debugger in your future...

Comment: I've formatted your code for you, but in the future, please consider doing this yourself. If we can read your code, we can better understand it. The opposite is quite true as well.

Comment: I believe that `total += (numberOfDays(month, year));` should be `total += (numberOfDays(m, year));`

Comment: are you serious, omg thank you so much Madprogrammer. haha just one thing. Thank you!! But how do I make it that if I enter 2015 it will be invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this...

```
for (int m= 1;  m < month;  m++)
    total += (numberOfDays(month, year));
```

is wrong, you are passing the value of `month` to this method each time it is called (`12` for example), meaning that each time you call it, it thinks the number of days in the month is 31 (because it is)...

Instead, pass `m`

```
for (int m= 1;  m < month;  m++)
    total += (numberOfDays(m, year));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but one question where will I make it so that if the user enter 2015 it will give a warning and return the value of zero.

Comment: Right before the loop would be my guess.  `if` the year `< 2015`, run the loop, otherwise display an error message

Comment: It print out invalid twice and then the number. Do I do it in the main method. Right before I called it?

Comment: You are calling `dayNumber` twice.  Make sure, if the year is `>= 2015`, the loop can not be executed..